# Changing the value of a dial slide with an input in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit, qslider

Well, I am kind of stuck on this issue - I am trying to change the value of a dial slider and I want to change it using an input with QLineEdit input field and so far I couldn't find anything that could have helped me on the internet.

Code snip

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEditGain_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QString getVal=ui->lineEditGain->text();
    // qint16 intVal = getVal.split(" ")[0].toInt();
    connect(getVal, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(setValue(QString)));
}
```

Comment: I understand that you want to change the slider from a lineedit, you put a number and it should update the slider

Comment: Besides I would like to mention that my dial has a maximum and minimum values (-127 and 127) and I have read at a couple of places that certain constraints and GUI elements do not really work well together like this.

Comment: I would recommend replacing QLineEdit with QSpinBox

Comment: QSpinBox is not exactly what I was looking for, also my biggest problem is "wiring" the two as I cannot figure out how to change the selected value on the dial with one more dynamically input one.

Comment: check my solution, please

Comment: Put this in to Slot: QRegExp re("\\d*");  // a digit (\d), zero or more times (*)
    if (re.exactMatch(arg1)){
        int value = arg1.toInt();
        if(value >= -127 && value<=127)
          slider->setValue(value);
    }

Comment: You already have the slot

Comment: update solution

Comment: Correct. I did add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create slots:

```
private slots:    
    void MySlot(QString text);
```

In the constructor connect `textChanged()` with `MySlot()`:

```
connect(lineedit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &YourWidget::MySlot);
```

and then

```
void YourWidget::MySlot(QString text)
{
    QRegExp re("\\d*");  // a digit (\d), zero or more times (*)
    if (re.exactMatch(text)){
        int value = text.toInt();
        if(value >= -127 && value<=127)
          slider->setValue(value);
    }
}
```

You could also place a QValidator

```
lineedit->setValidator( new QIntValidator(-127, 127, this) );
```

In your case:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEditGain_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QRegExp re("\\d*");  // a digit (\d), zero or more times (*)
    if (re.exactMatch(arg1)){
        int value = arg1.toInt();
        if(value >= -127 && value<=127)
            ui->slider->setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to fit it with my code, however I get this:
"D:\Qt Projects\OXforce\mainwindow.cpp:117: error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'QString' to 'const QObject *'
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called"

Comment: Added a snippet in the question. :)

Comment: Amazing, although this seemed like a huge hassle in order to do something so simple... 

Nevertheless, thank you very much!!! I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Mind if you can give me some advice on how to make it work with negative integers as well?

Comment: That is what I did! Thank you once again!